# Transit in Lisbon airport

Tags: transit, transit-visas, portugal, saudi-citizens, lis

I'm from Saudi Arabia, I have question my flight to CMN from LHR transit LIS 4 hours but I don't have Portugal transit visa, can I travel or not?

Comment: Have you tried http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-or-layover-in-the-schengen-area? Where do you get stuck?